# Table of contents in other languages

Tags: table-of-contents

I want "Innhald" instead of "Contents". How may I do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{verse}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
% Use PoetryTeX; http://www.ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}

% Use the PA5 paper size
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}


%\maketitle
%\makededication

% Number pages with small roman numerals (i, ii, iii, iv...)
\frontmatter

% TOC %
\maketoc

% TOP %
\renewcommand*{\topname}{Dikt} % Name for the table of poems
\maketop

\section{F\o reord}


\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

% Start numbering pages with normal arabic numerals.
\mainmatter


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I get the error File `Babel.sty' not found. ^^M

Comment: The `babel` package seems to be missing on your system.

Comment: I have used it several times before.

Comment: @leandris It worked now! You deserve some points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `babel` package can help by offering translations of the title of the table of contents or other terms such as "figure"  to different languages. Using `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}` in your example document gives the desired result:

[image]

You might also want to have a look at the list of options (starting on page 22 of the `babel` manual). Probably `norwegianbokmal`, `norwegiannynorsk` or `nynorsk` are also interesting.